# Git -- cloning a previous commit in a different folder than local working directory

Tags: git

On my local machine, I have a folder structure thus:

```
c:\myprojects\project1\
c:\myprojects\project2\
```

This has been git committed/pushed remotely to repository titled `myprojects`

I have a folder on my machine which is not under source control. This is

`c:\temp_outside_of_source_control\`

Suppose the repositories (online and local) have the following history of commits in reverse chronological order (SHAIDs):

```
abcdef #<---- current upto date one
ghijkl #<---- older commit
```

How can I download/clone/repo commit `ghijkl` to `c:\temp_outside_of_source_control\` without affecting/touching in any way the relationship that exists between the local `c:\myprojects\` and remote `myprojects`?

What I have tried:

(1) From inside of `c:\temp_outside_of_source_control\`, I ran

`git clone url_path_to_myprojects_repository`

This created

```
c:\temp_outside_of_source_control\myprojects\project1\
c:\temp_outside_of_source_control\myprojects\project2\
```

and the contents of this folder are upto date -- i.e., they are the commit abcdef. This, however, has the unfortunate side effect that this affects the content of `c:\myprojects\.git\` folder. I want the current relationship between my online repository and local repository to be completely untouched. Essentially, I want an earlier commit to be replicated in a non-source-controlled folder without this in any way impacting the current relationship between my source controlled folder locally and the online repository.

(2) From a git software (Git Graph in VSCode, if it matters), that shows a history of commits, I right clicked on commit `ghijkl` and pressed `checkout...` in the hope that it would ask me which folder locally I would like to check out to, but there was no such option. There was a warning:

`Are you sure you want to checkout commit ghijkl? This will result in a detached HEAD state.` This possibly will affect the relationship that exists between `c:\myprojects\` and the online repository `myprojects`.

---

ETA: As suggested by user knittl in the answer, I was able to zip the contents of a previous commit without affecting much else and download that locally via:

`git archive --format zip --output previous_commit.zip ghijkl`

However, I would still like to know if there is a way to directly replicate a previous commit to a user specified folder that is not under source control without "disturbing" the current relationship between the online repository and the source controlled folder.

---

ETA2: Indeed the method suggested by knittl is perfect for my purposes on ubuntu/wsl:

`git archive ghijkl | tar -xC temp_outside_source_control`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing clones/repositories and commits. Your command

```
git clone url_path_to_myprojects_repository
```

Is only missing one step:

```
git checkout ghijkl
```

This will get you the older commit. [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) accepts URLs to a repository and downloads the complete history of the repository and checks out the latest commit of the default branch by default. [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) usually expects a commit and will make your working tree on disk match the given commit from your local repository. The newer [`switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) subcommand does the same.

That said, if you are not interested in the history at all, you can easily create an [archive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) from any tree-ish (e.g. a commit):

```
cd url_path_to_myprojects_repository
git archive -o source.tar ghijkl
```

Or possibly even, depending on your remote repository configuration:

```
git archive -o source.tar --remote=url_of_origin_repository ghijkl
```

Later, you can extract the archive in any directory you wish. It is also possible to immediately extract the archive, without writing the file to disk:

```
git archive ghijkl | tar -xC temp_outside_source_control
```

Comment: Even though I ran `git checkout ghijkl` from within the temp folder outside of source control, after cloning the repo in this temp folder first, this does seem to affect the real relationship between `c:\myprojects\`  and `myprojects`. For instance, I notice that I have already a detached HEAD.

Comment: Furthermore, in commit `ghijkl` I did not have a file abc.txt. This was added in commit `abcdef`. When I first cloned the repository in the temp folder, file abc.txt was there. Then, when I ran `git checkout ghijkl`, this file continues to be there although it was not part of commit ghijkl

Comment: @Tryer a clone is a clone and as such operations in the clone do not affect the source repository. Usually there is a network inbetween, so it is physically impossible to do so. Cloning locally has a few caveats, but works the same in essence.

Comment: @Tryer are you sure the file was not part of an earlier commit? I doubt that Git will put arbitrary files in your working tree. If the file was tracked and only added in a later commit, checking out an older commit is going to remove the file. Compare the file contents after checking out the older commit. You will notice differences.

Comment: If that's not the case, please share more information. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70661968/edit) your question to include the relevant details, such as output of `git status`, `git diff`, `git remote -v`, `git reflog`, `git branch`, your currend working directory (i.e. output of `pwd` or paths you used with `cd`), any error messages or warnings, and exact commands which you have executed in order.

Comment: Let me work on creating a simple example. In the meantime, I tried the `git archive - o source.tar --remote=url ghijkl` command from inside of `c:\temp_outside_of_source_control\` Unfortunately, github, where this online repository is does not seem to support this. I get the error `fatal: operation not supported by protocol`

Comment: Your suggestion of zipping a previous commit worked. I had to follow a different method -- the one suggested https://www.markheath.net/post/zip-git-archive for instance worked.